# preg_match_all get the end of the expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have some lines:

```
[3G*2110620000*000A*UD]
[3G*2110620000*000A*LK][3G*2110620000*000A*LK,0,0,100]
[3G*2110620000*000A*LK,100]
[EL*2110620006*000A*LK,0,0],100]]]
```

I need to get an array as a result:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Manufacture] => 3G
            [DeviceId] => 2110620000
            [Length] => 000A
            [Command] => UD
        ),
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Manufacture] => 3G
            [DeviceId] => 2110620000
            [Length] => 000A
            [Command] => LK
        ),
    [2] => Array
        (
            [Manufacture] => 3G
            [DeviceId] => 2110620000
            [Length] => 000A
            [Command] => LK
            [Parameters] => 0,0,100
        ),
    [3] => Array
        (
            [Manufacture] => 3G
            [DeviceId] => 2110620000
            [Length] => 000A
            [Command] => LK
            [Parameters] => 100
        ),
    [4] => Array
        (
            [Manufacture] => 3G
            [DeviceId] => 2110620000
            [Length] => 000A
            [Command] => LK
            [Parameters] => 0,0],100]]
        ),
)
```

Each line can contain one or more commands.

1. The command starts with "[" and ends with "]".
2. The command must contain the manufacturer's name "3G" or "EL" after "[".
3. Next comes the "*" separator.
4. Next comes a 10-digit number is the device identifier.
5. Next comes is a 4-byte packet length.
6. Next comes a name of command (can be of arbitrary length).
7. Next comes the "," separator.
8. Next comes the command parameters (they may not be there, they can contain any characters, including "]" and "[").

I am trying to write a regex for these cases, but I am unable to highlight the parameters.

I tried

```
\[(?P<Manufacture>3G|EL)\*(?P<DeviceId>[0-9]{10})\*(?P<Length>[A-Z0-9]{4})\*(?P<Command>.+)[\]|,]{1}(?P<Parameters>.*)\]?
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Iq2Xf4/2

Answer (score 3):

The match should end with a closing `]` but the `Parameters` group can contain `[` and `]` as well.

One option is to match as least as possible characters until you reach another part that starts with 3G or EL or the end of the string after the closing square bracket.

```
\[(?P<Manufacture>3G|EL)\*(?P<DeviceId>[0-9]{10})\*(?P<Length>[A-Z0-9]{4})\*(?P<Command>[^[,\r\n]*)(?:,(?P<Parameters>.*?(?=](?:\[(?:3G|EL)|$))))?]
```

**Explanation**

- `\[` Match `[`
- `(?P<Manufacture>3G|EL)\*` Named group `Manufacture` match either `3G` or `EL` and `*`
- `(?P<DeviceId>[0-9]{10})\*` Named group `DeviceId` match 10 digits and `*`
- `(?P<Length>[A-Z0-9]{4})\*` Named group `Length` match 4 times one of A-Z or 0-9
- `(?P<Command>[^[,\r\n]*)` Named group `Command` match `[` followed by any char except `[` `,` or a newline
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `,(?P<Parameters>.*?` Match a `,` followed by any char as least as possible in group `Parameters`
  - `(?=](?:\[(?:3G|EL)|$))` Positive lookahead to assert what is at the right is either `[3G` or `[EL` or the end of the string
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `]` Match closing `]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wgWVQk/1)